# Not able to create an exposed dropdown via kotlin. requireContext is asking for parameters

Tags: list, kotlin, dropdown, kotlin-exposed

[Checkout this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ6lH.png)
Did the job as suggested by material.io but ain't working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you already have an answer, but in future make sure you post your code as opposed to an image. We need to be able to reproduce the  example ourselves so we can help. Take a look at how to produce a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the code in an activity, you can just use `this` instead of `requireContext()`. The latter is only available in Fragment classes.